# How can I make Windows 7 to NOT switch applications when I click on the current one?

Tags: windows-7, taskbar

When I accidentally click the icon of the current application (the one I am using now), Windows 7 switches me to the last application I have used.

It happens to me a lot because I tend to try and switch application when what I actually want to do is switch tabs on my browser. What I get is another application and not the current one.

This behavior is annoying to me. I want to stay in the same application and realize I actually wanted to switch to another tab.

How is it possible to change the behavior of clicking an open application on the taskbar?

Comment: I don't believe so.  This is a basic feature of Windows that has been around forever.  You are minimizing the window by clicking on the taskbar icon when its already maximized.

Comment: It isn't "switching" you to the last application, it is minimizing the current application you are using. If you did not have any applications open then it would show your desktop.

Comment: Look there for a solution: http://superuser.com/a/571313/195224