# How do I stop the win+# hotkey from minimizing the focused window?

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-shortcuts

I have several monitors and use the taskbar autohide feature together with fullscreen applications, so I don't know which window currently has focus. Pressing <kbd>win</kbd>+{currently focused window number} makes that window minimized and it is really annoying.

There is [a similar question](https://superuser.com/questions/470022) already, but it solves this problem for mouse clicking only.

Comment: So, what *do* you want to happen? Just nothing?

Comment: Yes, just nothing.

Comment: Is an AutoHotKey script a valid option? It would catch those [key combinations](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm) `{#1},{#2},{#3}...` and then do nothing. Haven't tested it so far but I guess its possible.

Comment: Ok, doing nothing in #1 handler really does nothing (no focusing even if that window does not have focus). So, I'm investigating how to also mimic the original behavior of <kbd>win</kbd>+# via AutoHotKey...

Comment: Ok, current idea is to intercept those hotkeys, check if current active window (explained here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9115495/how-to-get-the-active-windows-title-with-autohotkey ) is the same as the window which will be triggered by the hotkey (no idea how to do this) and do nothing if they match (easy =), otherwise pass hotkey through to activate/run that window (explained here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2349694/how-can-i-pass-the-intercepted-key-through-to-an-application-in-autohotkey ).

Comment: Getting handles of windows associated with taskbar items involves some winapi tricks (explained here http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10497/A-tool-to-order-the-window-buttons-in-your-taskbar (pre-windows7 method unfortunately =( )), but it looks like it is possible to implement it in AHK.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to intercept the keystroke using a program like [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/). Once installed, you can write and run scripts that intercept keyboard input. The simplest kind of script is called a "[hotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm)". You simply state a keystroke and the desired action.

You could define the `Windows`+`Num` keystroke to do nothing, which would prevent it from being sent to Windows to toggle the visibility of the programs at that slot in the taskbar.

```
#1::
#2::
#3::
```

You will lose the capability of *launching* an application in the taskbar with this simple, global interception. But, I'm sure someone can recommend how to write a script that is aware of the window's focus and taskbar slot.

Comment: Thank you, this solution was already discussed in comments above...

Comment: Oh snap, the comments were collapsed when I answered! If I get around to it, I'll try to actually make a script that behaves with focused windows.